# Error report - Check and Remove files,Registry, and Enviromental Variables

Tags: powershell

I'm still pretty new to scripting so this is probably a lot clunkier than it needs to be, or either completely wrong. Using PowerShell I'm trying remove a program, and cleanup after it by deleting the files, registry entries and environmental variables from many servers. My script I pipe to tee and a file for error logging. The problem I'm running into is it's not working but I'm generating no errors for me to troubleshoot. Either when I run it directly or tee it out. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$servers = import-csv -Path .\ServerList.txt
foreach ($server in $Servers) {
    Write-host "Copying .bat file to $server at F:"
    Copy-item -path \\e-fake\d-fake\o-fake\AdminScripts\PatrolRemove\PtrAgentRemove.bat -Destination f:\PtrAgentRemove.bat
    start-sleep -Seconds 2
    F:\PtrAgentRemove.bat
    start-sleep -Seconds 5


    $regkeypath = "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BMC Software"
    $regValue = (Get-ItemProperty $regkeypath).test -eq $null
    If ($regValue -eq $false) {
        Remove-Item "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BMC Software"
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Host "The BMC Software registry entry does not exist, skipping the registry removal step"
    }

    If ($regValue -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "Registry entry Succefully removed"
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Host "Failed to remove BMC Software registry entry"
    }

    Write-host "Removing Enviromental Variables"
    $ENVPHome = get-childitem Env:\PATROL_HOME
    $ENVPTemp = Get-ChildItem Env:\PATROL_Temp
    $envPHtest = Test-Path Env:\PATROL_HOME
    $envPTtest = Test-Path Env:\PATROL_Temp
    If ($envPHtest -eq $true) {
        Remove-item Env:\PATROL_HOME
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " Env:\PATROL_Home does not exist on $server"
    }

    If ($envPTtest -eq $true) {
        Remove-item Env:\PATROL_TEMP
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " Env:\PATROL_Temp does not exist on $server"
    }

    Write-host "Testing Enviromrntal Variables"
    $envPHtest = Test-Path Env:\PATROL_HOME
    $envPTtest = Test-Path Env:\PATROL_Temp
    If ($envPHtest -eq $false) {
        Write-host " Env:\PATROL_Home does is not on $server"
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " Removal of Env:\PATROL_Home failed $server"
    }

    If ($envPTtest -eq $false) {
        Write-host " Env:\PATROL_TEMP does is not on $server"
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " Removal of Env:\PATROL_TEMP failed $server"
    }

    Write-Host "Removing F:Patrol directory"
    $PatrolFDIR = Get-childitem F:\Patrol
    $PatrolCDIR = Get-Childitem C:\users\Patrol8
    $PatrolUDIR = Get-Childitem U:\users\Patrol8
    $PatrolFDIRTest = Test-path F:\Patrol
    $PatrolCDIRTest = Test-path c:\users\Patrol8
    $PatrolUDIRTest = Test-path U:\users\Patrol8

    If ($PatrolFDIRTest -eq $true) {
        Remove-item $PatrolFDIR
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " F:\Patrol does not exist on $server"
    }

    If ($PatrolCDIRTest -eq $true) {
        Remove-item $PatrolCDIR
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " C:\users\Patrol8 does not exist on $server"
    }
    If ($PatrolUDIRTest -eq $true) {
        Remove-item $PatrolUDIR
    } 
    Else {
        Write-host " U:\users\Patrol8 does not exist on $server"
    }

}        
Write-host "Script succussfully ran, please check the log file for errors"
```

Comment: what is in the bat file? the Powershell code you have is it intended to run on the management station or on the remote host?

Comment: The .bat file simply executes a syntax that's specific for the removal of the application from the vendor. The script is ran from a management server that has access to all the servers in all of the domains. Starting at the for-each statement in the script, everything should be running on each remote host.